# UWP button not firing event

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I m working on a UWP project. I have two buttons to go from one page to another one. But I don't understand why the button is never called, I try different tutorials and technique it doesn't work.

```
<Page
    x:Class="MultiplatformMvvm.UWP.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:MultiplatformMvvm.UWP"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Page.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>

            <Style x:Key="textBlockStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="12,20,12,12"/>
                <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="24"/>
            </Style>

            <Style x:Key="buttonStyle" TargetType="Button">
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="12"/>
                <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Purple"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground"  Value="White"/>
            </Style>

        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Page.Resources>

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="Un café !" Style="{StaticResource textBlockStyle}"/>
            <Button x:Name="coffeeButton" Style="{StaticResource buttonStyle}" >
                Go Coffee
            </Button>
            <Button x:Name="myContactsButton" Style="{StaticResource buttonStyle}">
                My contacts
            </Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

My C# code :

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        coffeeButton.Click += coffeeButton_Click;
    }

    void coffeeButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // I never enter here
        Frame.Navigate(typeof(CoffeeListPage));
    }

    private void myContactsButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // I never enter here
        Frame.Navigate(typeof(ContactListPage));
    }
}
```

Comment: You are creating Click Event before the UI Is rendered. thats why click event is not being created ( atleast this is what i understand.) Try this in UI Itself. `<Button x:Name="coffeeButton" Style="{StaticResource buttonStyle}" Content="Go Coffee" Tapped="coffeeButton_Tapped" />`

Comment: I tried it but not working

Comment: Do you get an error? or Click/Tap event is not fired?

Comment: No errors, just nothing happen

Comment: Can you create a blank project with 2 pages, put button in first page and see if it navigates to second page on Tap Event when you Attach it in XAML?

Comment: I think you are in the right way, I put a break point in the coffeeButton after the InitializeComponent and it's not called

Comment: Yes I try wait a minute

Comment: @AVKNaidu That's works perfectly in an other project why ?

Comment: @AVKNaidu I clean the code and clean the build project it works, it was a cache problem... :( thanks for your help !

Comment: Glad that worked. I would suggest you put your experience with this issue as an answer and mark it as accepted so that someone else who has the same issue will be benefited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally clean all the cache in the UWP project and rebuild and it finally works. 
Hope it helps someone.

Comment: Thank your for sharing your suggestion. It solved my same issue, as well.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:
- Attaching a handler to the button in xaml itself and see it that works?
- In case you are using Bindings, then adding a command binding?

Also in your scenario,try this:
In your constructor after the InitializeComponent(); add:

Loaded += (s, e) => { coffeeButton.Click += coffeeButton_Click; };

see if that works.

Comment: Could you give us the buttonStyle? Is it possible some behavior mat be overridden in the style? In UWP apps since the idea is that your apps will run on a mobile device, its better to handle the Tapped event as thats fired when a user Taps, click is fired when mouse click happens

Comment: I clean the code and clean the build project it works, it was a cache problem... :( thanks for your help !